# Delphi PerlRegEx: Link .obj files statically so they don't depend on msvcrt.dll

Tags: c, regex, delphi, pcre

I've used the builtin `RegularExpressions` unit from Delphi XE2 for some time until I figured out that its object files (`.obj`) depend on `msvcrt.dll`, wrapped by `System.Win.Crtl`. It makes me a little bit sad because I've always been proud of the way Delphi can build executables with no runtime dependencies, unlike VB or VC++ (by default).

I tried to compile/link the C `.obj` files statically so they wouldn't depend on `msvcrt.dll` but my C/C++ skills are limited. I tried to do it in Visual Studio Express with no success. Is there a way to accomplish that for both Win32 and Win64 platforms?

The version of `PerlRegEx` I'm using is `7.9 2009-04-11`, available here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/download/TPerlRegEx.zip. `.obj` files are in the `pcre` folder.

The C sources for the `.obj` files are here: http://ufpr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/7.9/pcre-7.9.zip

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

I was looking only at the import table of the exe. Didn't see that msvcrt.dll gets loaded during execution even when I don't use RegularExpressions unit. I've seen some errors related to it in the past and misassociated with the fact that RegularExpressions causes msvcrt.dll to be added to the imports. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I don't understand. A plain vanilla Delphi VCL forms app loads msvcrt.dll. This is a system component. You are happy to link against user32.dll? And most C++ toolchains that I know of on Windows can produce executables that don't have non-system dependencies.

Comment: What Windows exe's don't use MS c-runtime?

Comment: Actually many of them. From delphi 7 to 2010 you can build applications that don't use msvcrt.dll at all. And although it's a system component, I've seen several client machines where it was not installed by default.

Comment: @Kekas Not recently. It's been a system component since Windows 2000. I've been shipping programs relying on msvcrt for years and years and have never once had a missing dependency.

Comment: Delphi applications since version 1 have always had dependencies on system libraries (user, gdi, kernel). MSVCRT.DLL is a system library. It's part of the OS, just like what now is user32.DLL. You have nothing to be sad about, because nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty much pointless task. A plain vanilla VCL forms application will load the system msvcrt library. Yes, this is a system library. It is distributed as a standard OS library. All systems have it. In that regard it is no different from user32, advapi and so on.

So, by removing the dependency that the regex code has on msvcrt will not make your program have any fewer dependencies. What's more, there's nothing to be afraid of in taking a dependency on a system library.

You might ask why a Delphi application has a dependency on msvcrt. It comes about because of this:

1. The `WideString` type is a loose wrapper around the system `BSTR` type.
2. The implementation of `BSTR` is provided by the oleaut32 library.
3. A plain vanilla Delphi program, that uses no units at all, has a load-time dependency on 
   oleaut32 in order to provide, for instance, `SysFreeString`.
4. The oleaut32 library in turn has a dependency on msvcrt.

So, not matter what you do, you will not be able to remove the dependency on msvcrt.

---

However, to answer your question, because I enjoy answering questions, especially ones on linking compiled objects, here is what you need to do:

1. Take a copy of `System.RegularExpressionsAPI.pas` and place it in your project's source folder. Add it to the project. This is now the unit that the rest of the regular expression library stands on top of.
2. At the top of the implementation section, remove the reference to `System.Win.Crtl`.
3. Compile your project.

You will find that the code will not compile, and gives the following errors:

```
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_strncmp'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_memmove'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_memset'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_memcpy'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_memcmp'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_strlen'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__ltolower'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_islower'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '__ltoupper'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isdigit'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isupper'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isalnum'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isspace'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isxdigit'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isgraph'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isprint'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_ispunct'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_iscntrl'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_isalpha'
E2065 Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: '_strchr'
```

In order for the compiler to compile this unit, it must be able to resolve these symbols in the modified `System.RegularExpressionsAPI.pas` unit. Using `System.Win.Crtl` is what makes that happen in the plain RTL. If you want to avoid linking `System.Win.Crtl` then you need to provide implementations. For instance, here is `_strlen`.

```
function _strlen(P: PAnsiChar): size_t; cdecl;
begin
  Result := System.SysUtils.StrLen(P);
end;
```

Add that to the modified `System.RegularExpressionsAPI.pas` unit and you've resolved the dependency. You now just need to keep doing that for all the others. This is regulation, link to compiled object fare.

But, as I have tried to make clear, I would not recommend doing this. You are creating work for yourself that will bring no discernible gain. You'll end up with even more code in your program than before. And there's every chance that you'll make mistakes implementing these C runtime functions. You'll invest a whole heap of time, and end up with a program that is worse than what you have now.

Comment: I had that idea some time ago and I decided not to implement every function myself. I don't agree that msvcrt.dll is like user32.dll or any other standard OS libraries. I've seen windows XP machines with replaced versions of it for some purpose. Some softwares do it. I didn't see any software replacing user32.dll or kernel32.dll before. That's the reason why I wanted to remove its dependency. I thought i had that option and I will run some more tests.

Comment: @Kekas I don't see how you can disagree with my analysis. You can check it yourself with Dependency Walker. Note that oleaut32.dll takes a dependency on msvcrt.dll. The fact that some crappy software might attempt to overwrite msvcrt is hardly the point. That software could attempt to overwrite anything else. The msvcrt DLL is a protected system library and anything that tries to overwrite it will fail because the system protects its DLLs.

Comment: I'm not really sure what more you want. Obviously it's up to you what you think about the status of msvcrt. However, your Delphi executables do depend on it whether you like it or not. You asked how to link the regex code without relying on msvcrt, and I've shown you. What else are you looking for here?

Comment: You are right. oleaut32.dll depends on msvcrt.dll. Although you were sure of your answer I still had to verify. You could cut your answer in half because as you said, the second part is pointless. Someone could think it's an alternative.

Comment: That "crappy software" might have been Microsoft Visual C++ (Redistributable) :-)

Comment: @Kekas The second half of the answer is the answer to the question that you asked. Namely how to link without using Crtl. So, that part of the answer I won't remove.

Comment: @TLama msvcrt.dll is the MSVC6 runtime. System protected these days. Modern MSVC runtime use numbered dll names like msvcrt130

Comment: @Davivd, yeah, but OP was talking about Windows XP machines with replaced versions of msvcrt.dll which might well happen by a regular update.

Comment: @TLama Windows update will update the DLLs on all versions, not just XP.